# Angular2 Template not updating when using Array.slice() on a property

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Edit: After I did some improvements and refactoring, the the view wont update again. I edited my changes below.

I don't really know, how to put my question in a title, so here's the longer version.

I have a component, and on init it gets data as an array and stores it. On the template side, I iterate over this array via *ngFor. Now, when I slice an element out of the array or append one, how can I "tell" *ngFor to iterate again and display the change?

```
private array: String;  

ngOnInit(){
    this.array = ["lel", "soos", "meme"];
}

updateValues(){
    this.array.splice(1, 1);
}


<div *ngFor="let item of array">
    ...
</div>
```

After updateValues(), there are still 3 items displayed in the view.

I appreciate any help!

Edit: Some more detailed code:

```
confirmPostDeletion(post: Post) {
    this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ProjectDetailConfirmComponent);
    this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if (result === 'yes') {
            this.deletePost(post)
        }
        this.dialogRef = null;
    });

}

deletePost(post: Post) {
    this.postService.deletePost(post).subscribe(
        message => this.information = message,
        error => this.errorMessage = error,
        () => {
            this.project.posts.splice(this.project.posts.indexOf(post), 1);
        }
    );
}
```

And the template part:

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let post of project.posts | orderBy: 'id':false">
    <div class="card-block">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <h4 class="card-title">{{ post.headline }}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1 ml-3">
                            <div *ngIf="adminMode" class="btn-group-sm " role="group">
                                <button id="adminGroupDrop" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
                                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Edit
                                </button>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="adminGroupDrop">
                                    <button type="button" class="dropdown-item">Bearbeiten</button>
                                    <button type="button" (click)="confirmPostDeletion(post)" class="dropdown-item">Löschen</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ post.content }}</p>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its seems to be working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/41AsCOjKfZb8PQ7TszVH?p=preview), what is the problem?

Comment: Can you `console.log(this.project.posts)` after the line when you perform `this.project.posts.splice(this.project.posts.indexOf(post), 1);` to make sure the `posts` array is in the state we're expecting it to be? (i.e. the object is really removed)

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your example is that you don't actually modify the array (array.slice **does not change** the content of the array - it just returns a part of it).

If you just properly mutate (modify) the value of a variable defined on your component, it should find out about this change automatically. Try it with something like:

```
updateValues(){
    this.array.splice(1, 1);
}
```

(**`splice`** in contrast to **`slice`** does change the array it operates on)

Comment: Hey! Iam actually splicing the array. I just got it wrong in my example. Still doesnt work...

Comment: I've just tried to reproduce it and it _should work_ http://plnkr.co/edit/2asEHcJyFtiOIWzY6DOc . Can you provide a working code where it's broken?

Answer (score 1):

The splice method does not modify an array.

This method returns the modified array.
For example:

```
data = arrayValue.splice(1,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array works on references not values, so if you remove any item, it only removes it's value but not the reference, So below are the steps which should resolve the issue,

```
ngOnInit(){
this.array = ["lel", "soos", "meme"];
}

updateValues(){
let tempArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.array));//To get completely new copy without references 
tempArray.splice(1, 1);
this.array = tempArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually call the `ngChanges()` method on my component:

```html
<app-my-component #myComponentEl [list]="myArray" />
```

```
@ViewChild('myComponentEl') public myComponentEl!: MyComponent;
public myArray = [];

updateArray(newItem): void {
  //add as the next-to-last item in the array
  this.myArray.splice(this.myArray.length - 1, 0, newItem);
  this.myComponentEl.ngOnChanges(); //I do not understand why, but the UI will not detect the change in the array so we have to manually call this to make the new item appear!
}
```

Once I do this, that component will fire its `ngOnChanges` method which I already set up previously.

Answer (score -1):

Can you post rest of your code where `updateValues()` been call, need to make sure where `updateValues()` get calls.

Also in the `updateValues()` you can add a flag to make sure after array gets update, and put `*ngIf` in the `<div *ngFor="let item of array"></div>`

For example:
    private array: String;
    isUpdated: boolean;

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.array = ["lel", "soos", "meme"];
    this.isUpdated = false;
}

updateValues(){
    this.array.splice(1, 1);
    this.isUpdated = true;
}


<div *ngIf="isUpdated" *ngFor="let item of array">
    ...
</div>
```